# Execute task that needs login by using oauth consumerkey and consumersecret

Tags: python, authentication, http, curl, oauth

I am trying to log into a webpage to execute a task...

I can execute tasks that do not require login, but the ones that require that, I can not...

I have this:

```
"oauthConsumerKey": example-asas-xxxx-asss-qwqweqweqweqwe
"oauthConsumerSecret": aaaaaaaa-22ce-479e-83c4-yyyyyyyyy
```

In the API documentation, this is the curl used to load a file:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.example.stack.com/load/v1/load_file?clientCode=12345678&idCompany=11111111&idProcedure=11111111&fileType=File&numberOfBytes=90" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@file.xml;type=text/xml"
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to "copy as a curl" with the developer tools of my browser the petition of login:

```
curl 'https://api.example.stack.com/test/v1/code?oauth_consumer_key=example-asas-xxxx-asss-qwqweqweqweqwe&oauth_nonce=493179345&oauth_timestamp=1664784822&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=xdlTTcThh46FuTqftVYjS%2F8tIFk%3D' \
  -H 'authority: api.example.stack.com' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: _ga=GA1.3.1133377053.1663598880; JSESSIONID=C-rHN7BIjuJl2FrBWqqAulpLgcSJUvibUYvra6dq.mlasl' \
  -H 'referer: https://api.example.stack.com/loader/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed
```

But it does not work then I execute it in my terminal...

I saw that with a .pem certificate it is much more easier, but I would like to do it by using both tokens.

Comment: Does the service provide a way of retrieving a Auth Token (Basic or Bearer)? With that you can do an extra call to the oauth to retrieve a token to then attach a `Authorisation` header to the call you are trying to do

Comment: @SirPeople in the documentation it specifies that the oauthroken should be empty

Comment: Can you share the documentation? At least to understand the auth possibilities here

Comment: @SirPeople https://documentacion.cnmc.es/doc/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10682370